# Skipping page number on the coversheet in Access Report, and new page number from the 2nd page by group

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

I was able to find an example code for Access VBA to insert "Page of pages" per group header. Each group is an individual invoice to our client.

Now, I want to add the cover sheet that shows the total invoice amount, and I can do that. But the cover sheet messes up the page number of the very first invoice following the cover sheet.

For example, The first invoice is only one page. So without the coversheet, the page number shows as "page 1 of 1".

But when I add the Report Header, and force the new page "After the selection", the coversheet shows *page 1 of 2* and the first invoice shows *page 2 of 2*.

Is there a way to not have the page number at all on the coversheet, and the following page has the new page 1 numbering?

ctlGrpPages is the control that shows page numbers, and it is placed in the page footer.

Thank you very much in advance.

```
Private Sub PageFooterSection_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As 
Integer)
Dim i As Integer


  If Me.Pages = 0 Then
    ReDim Preserve GrpArrayPage(Me.Page + 1)
ReDim Preserve GrpArrayPages(Me.Page + 1)
GrpNameCurrent = Me![Claim Number]
If GrpNameCurrent = GrpNamePrevious Then
    GrpArrayPage(Me.Page) = GrpArrayPage(Me.Page - 1) + 1
    GrpPages = GrpArrayPage(Me.Page)
        For i = Me.Page - ((GrpPages) - 1) To Me.Page
            GrpArrayPages(i) = GrpPages
        Next i
Else
    GrpPage = 1
    GrpArrayPage(Me.Page) = GrpPage
    GrpArrayPages(Me.Page) = GrpPage
End If
 Else
   Me!ctlGrpPages.Value = "Page " & GrpArrayPage(Me.Page) & " of " & 
GrpArrayPages(Me.Page)
  End If
  GrpNamePrevious = GrpNameCurrent
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What is your setting for report property PageFooter? Have you tried 'Not with Rpt Hdr'?

Comment: Thank you June7. I tried looking for Report Property Page Footer, but in Access 2013, I was not able to find this setting. Do you know if this exists in Access 2013?

Comment: FYI - For now, I added a dummy record without claim number which forces the sort by order to show this dummy record to be the very first record to show up. This forces the report header only to have page 1 of 1. But I would like to know how to set the property correctly in 2013.

Comment: You have the report selected (click the square in upper left of report). The property would be found on the Properties Sheet format tab. Never used Access 2013 but can't imagine that property would be removed.

Comment: The property sheet is there, but I don't know which one I should change. Anyway, I found a sort of work-around method. Thank you for your input.